# setInterval and 12 hour clock in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to write a script that changes the hour displayed inside a `<span>` every second, starting from 8AM, and which keeps repeating like a 12 hours clock (11AM, 12PM, ..., 11PM, 12AM, 1AM, ...).

The image will change at 8AM and 8PM. At 8PM, the image will change to a sleeping face, and at 8AM the image will change back to a smile face. However, that is not a problem.

The problems are:

1. When I set `var hour = Number(document.getElementById("time").textContent);` then `setInterval` repeats the time without any problem. However, when I set `var hour = 8` instead, and keep same code, then `setInterval` repeats only once. Can you let me know why it is like that and how to fix it with `var hour = 8`?
2. When the hour is repeatedly increased, I cannot make it smart to change back to AM when it reaches to 12 after passing noon (12PM). For example, the code works fine from 8AM to 11PM but when it reaches to 12, the PM does not change to AM. Can you show me how to fix it?
3. Lastly when I change `var period = "AM"` instead of using DOM `getElementByID` like above and keep same code, then it runs to 1PM and then changes to 2AM and never changes to PM again. Can you explain to me why it happens?

If you do not know what I am talking about, you can run my code and to understand more.

Here is the HTML:

```
<h2>Life goes on!</h2>
<p>The current time is : <span id = "time">8</span> <span id = "period"> AM</span></p>
<img id = "emoticon" src = "smile.gif" alt = "awake">
```

And here is my JavaScript code:

```
setInterval(function () {
    var hour = Number(document.getElementById("time").textContent);
    hour++;
    var period = document.getElementById("period").textContent;

    if (hour >= 12) {
        hour = hour - 12;
        period = "PM";
    }

    if (hour == 0) {
        hour = 12;
    }


    document.getElementById("time").textContent = hour;
    document.getElementById("period").textContent = period;
    if (hour == 8 && period == "PM") {
        document.getElementById("emoticon").src = "sleep.gif";
        document.getElementById("emoticon").alt = "sleep";
    } else if (hour == 8 && period == "AM") {
        document.getElementById("emoticon").src = "smile.gif";
        document.getElementById("emotion").alt = "awake";
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't count to `24`  and if `time > 12:00` then show `time - 12 hours PM` otherwise `time  AM`?

Comment: To **1.**  you mean if you replacing `var hour = Number(document.getElementById("time").textContent);` with `var hour=8;`?  `setInterval` will still be called every second, but because you set the `hour` always to `8`  the result written to the element `#time`  will always be `9`  that why you only see one change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me explain the problems of your code, using the same three points you made:

1. Your problem about `var hour = 8;` is that, if you set the hour inside the `setInterval` callback, **your hour will be set to `8` at any second**. Therefore, your `setInterval` doesn't work only once, but it gets run infinite times setting the time always to `9`. To avoid this, you can **move the variable outside** and make it global, setting it to `8` **before** starting the `setInterval`.
2. To change "PM" back to "AM" when it reaches 12PM, just add an `if` statement (or, better, a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), like I did in the snippet below) to **check if the period is either "PM" or "AM", and behave consequently**. Also, be careful with the check: if you check directly on `.textContent` be sure that the text inside the `<span>` doesn't have any trailing space: **use `.trim()` to remove extra spaces** at the beginning and at the end of the string.
3. This is the same problem of point 1: you should make the variable `period` global, and then start the `setInterval`.

The logic of the following script is simple:

1. Increase the `hour` by 1
2. If the new `hour` equals 12, then switch to "PM" or back to "PM"
3. If the new `hour` is greater than 12, then reset it to 1
4. Display hour and period
5. Change from `smile.gif` to `sleep.gif` when it's 8PM, and vice versa when it's 8AM.

I also made some little changes to make code easier and faster to read. **Here is a working code snippet**:

```js
var hour = 8,
    period = "AM";

setInterval(function() {
    if (++hour >= 12) {
        if (hour > 12) hour = 1;
        else period = (period == "PM") ? "AM" : "PM";
    }

    document.getElementById("time").textContent = hour;
    document.getElementById("period").textContent = period;

    if (hour == 8 && period == "PM") {
        document.getElementById("emoticon").src = "sleep.gif";
        document.getElementById("emoticon").alt = "sleep";
    } else if (hour == 8 && period == "AM") {
        document.getElementById("emoticon").src = "smile.gif";
        document.getElementById("emotion").alt = "awake";
    }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<h2>Life goes on!</h2>
<p>The current time is: <span id="time">8</span> <span id="period">AM</span></p>
<img id="emoticon" src="smile.gif" alt="awake">
```

Here it is, it works fine now, **give it a try** clicking on "Run code snippet".

Comment: perfect case for a ternary: `period = period == "PM" ? "AM" : "PM";`

Comment: Thanks for your answers. It helped me a lot. The only problem I have now is when 12 is noon, it supposes to be PM instead of AM and when it reaches midnight, it supposes to be AM instead of PM

Comment: @navygeek sorry for the mistake, I updated the code in my answer, now it's correct.

Comment: @navygeek you're welcome, if you found my answer to solve your question please consider marking it as correct to let future users find the solution easily.

Comment: I already did that. Thanks for reminding me! Another question for you is: You said setting up local variable inside setInterval callback function, that value will be set forever. Thus, how it works with DOM property var hour = getElementById("hour").textContent instead. That variable is set inside but the value is increased every second. Thanks

Comment: @navygeek that variable will not be set forever! The `setInterval` function will call your function every second, and the variable gets set each time the function is called (so every second). If you write `var a = "something"` that variable will be set to `"something"` **every time** your function is executed. If you use `var a = document.getElementById('#someid').textContent` instead, you are getting the text inside that particular element. Now, since that you're changing that text every second within your function, the variable will be different every time (even if it's not global).